# jQuery problem on click event triggering hidden content

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to load inline hidden content by fading it inside another div. The thing is that I can't prevent the content from being duplicated when there's more than one div with hidden content that have the same classes.

Here is a jsfiddle for better understanding: http://jsfiddle.net/EjU7M

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: So, when one of the `.link` elements is clicked, you want only the *previous* `.remove` element to be removed, and the *previous* `.hidden` text to be displayed?

Comment: Yes exactly I want that but without affecting others divs. I mean I want the event only to be applied once when u click an only .link. For example if u remove that extra .box, .full_text and .link you could see the event working well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you were querying all elements with a `classname` you will need to traverse the dom and match the elments near your link.

```
$('.link').click(function() {
    var $box = $(this).prevAll(".box:first"); //find the nearest .box
    var $remove = $b.find(".remove"); //find the remove in that box.
    var $text = $(this).prevAll(".full_text:first"); //find the text
    $remove.stop().animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, 'fast', function() {
        $remove.remove();
        $text.stop().fadeTo('fast', 1).appendTo($box);
    });
    return false;
})
```

**Code example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/EjU7M/1/).**

Comment: Yay! Thats what I wanted!! Thank you very much. Very kind of you :)

Comment: @Mark my final code seems that it doesn't have more than one .box container as it only needs to be updated. See this code example: http://jsfiddle.net/EjU7M/2/ kinda need to update the .box with display text 2 hidden content and then some kind of "close" link to back to the original .box content. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Jackson, I think this is what you need.  http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/EjU7M/3/ , with only one box and a way to revert back to the original text.

Comment: @Mark Yes!! Thanks again for taking the time! Is there any easy to fire the revert only if the display text is showed? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to let you know that I sorted it out myself :)

Comment: @Mark I've updated the jsfiddle with the new features, I'm only missing the revert button to work separately http://jsfiddle.net/EjU7M/4/ tried to tweak your code to make it work but nothing changed. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: @Jackson, issue was the removal and addition of the `.revert` link.  easiest way was to put the revert link in the `.box` so it is not altered.  see: http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/EjU7M/5/

Comment: @Mark Yes I tried that. But if you take a look the "revert" link is not fading, I wanna attach that link to every hidden bio and make it fade like everything else. Kinda make it work by adding `var $rv = $('.revert:first');` but I'm not cappable to fade the `originalText` See http://jsfiddle.net/EjU7M/6/

Comment: If that is the case, you can replace `.click()` with `.live("click", )`  seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/EjU7M/7/

Comment: Meh didn't thought it was that simple! Thanks man, you're a lifesaver :)))